# Cannot refresh gradle project in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

Why does this happen? There is no reason, I'm just trying to press the refresh button and it never works.

```
Error:Timeout waiting to lock buildscript class cache for build file '/home/dac/proj/spring-boot-master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jetty-jsp/build.gradle' (/home/dac/.gradle/caches/2.3/scripts/build_68kj36zmyqst1ei1zilpv1rml/ProjectScript/buildscript). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Owner PID: unknown
Our PID: 9475
Owner Operation: unknown
Our operation: Initialize cache
Lock file: /home/dac/.gradle/caches/2.3/scripts/build_68kj36zmyqst1ei1zilpv1rml/ProjectScript/buildscript/cache.properties.lock
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are seeing is likely related to [GRADLE-2795](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2795). Try to upgrade Gradle to 2.14 (which is the latest final version of Gradle at the time of writing). It should have this issue fixed.

Comment: To get around the issue you will need to upgrade. A newer version of Gradle will also provide significant performance improvements.

Comment: It was possible to upgrade from this repo `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle` Now I restart IntelliJ to see...

Comment: It's best practice to use the Gradle Wrapper to determine the compatible Gradle version for a project. You shouldn't rely on the installed version of Gradle on your machine.

Comment: But I am using the "default gradle wrapper" in IntelliJ.